# Draw Circles in OpenLayers with Lat/Lon and Radius

Tags: openlayers

I am plotting IGC tracks and want to add circles based on certain checkpoints on the route. I tried using this solution: [Draw a circle with defined diameter in OpenLayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996409/draw-a-circle-with-defined-diameter-in-openlayers)

but can't figure out how to implement it in a code such as this one: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/igc.html

Essentially, something like this: [image]

How do I add the circle?

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough. I need to know how to draw the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to plot the circles. I figured out that I needed more structure to the code to add the circles:

1. Define the circle
2. Add circle feature
3. Create a layer
4. Add the layer to the map

I followed an additional example here: http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter04_03_styling.html

I am new to OpenLayers (and JavaScript) but the structure is logical and easy to replicate.

[image]

My full code here. You would just need to add IGC files and API key:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>IGC example</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/build/ol.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <input id="time" type="range" value="0" steps="1" />
    <div class="span4 offset4 pull-right">
      <div id="info" class="alert alert-success">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<script>


            // Geometries
            var point =  new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.transform([-96.1543889, 29.2542778], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), 30000 );
            var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.transform([-96.1543889, 29.2542778], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), 10000 );

            // Features
            var pointFeature = new ol.Feature(point);
            var circleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);

            // Source and vector layer
            var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                features: [pointFeature, circleFeature]
            });

            var style = new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(20, 100, 240, 0.3)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    width: 3,
                    color: 'rgba(0, 100, 240, 0.8)'
                }),
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(55, 200, 150, 0.5)'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        width: 10,
                        color: 'rgba(55, 200, 150, 0.8)'
                    }),
                    radius: 7
                }),
            });

            var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSource,
                style: style
            });


var colors = {
  'MH': 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7)',
  'BW': 'rgba(0, 215, 255, 0.7)',
  'Sylvain Dhonneur': 'rgba(0, 165, 255, 0.7)',
  'Tom Payne': 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.7)',
  'Ulrich Prinz': 'rgba(0, 215, 255, 0.7)'
};

var styleCache = {};
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  var color = colors[feature.get('PLT')];
  var styleArray = styleCache[color];
  if (!styleArray) {
    styleArray = [new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: color,
        width: 3
      })
    })];
    styleCache[color] = styleArray;
  }
  return styleArray;
};

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

var igcUrls = [
  'BW.igc',
  'MH.igc',
  'data/igc/Sylvain-Dhonneur.igc',
  'data/igc/Tom-Payne.igc',
  'data/igc/Ulrich-Prinz.igc'
];

function get(url, callback) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open('GET', url);
  client.onload = function() {
    callback(client.responseText);
  };
  client.send();
}

var igcFormat = new ol.format.IGC();
for (var i = 0; i < igcUrls.length; ++i) {
  get(igcUrls[i], function(data) {
    var features = igcFormat.readFeatures(data,
        {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
  });
}

var time = {
  start: Infinity,
  stop: -Infinity,
  duration: 0
};
vectorSource.on('addfeature', function(event) {
  var geometry = event.feature.getGeometry();
  time.start = Math.min(time.start, geometry.getFirstCoordinate()[2]);
  time.stop = Math.max(time.stop, geometry.getLastCoordinate()[2]);
  time.duration = time.stop - time.start;
});


var wharton = [-96.1543889, 29.2542778]; // caution partner, read on...
// since we are using OSM, we have to transform the coordinates...
var whartonMercator = ol.proj.fromLonLat(wharton);




var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM({
        attributions: [
          new ol.Attribution({
            html: 'All maps &copy; ' +
                '<a href="http://www.opencyclemap.org/">OpenCycleMap</a>'
          }),
          ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION
        ],
        url: 'https://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      })
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: styleFunction
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: true
    })
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: whartonMercator,
    zoom: 9
  })
});



var point = null;
var line = null;
var displaySnap = function(coordinate) {
  var closestFeature = vectorSource.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(coordinate);
  var info = document.getElementById('info');
  if (closestFeature === null) {
    point = null;
    line = null;
    info.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  } else {
    var geometry = closestFeature.getGeometry();
    var closestPoint = geometry.getClosestPoint(coordinate);
    if (point === null) {
      point = new ol.geom.Point(closestPoint);
    } else {
      point.setCoordinates(closestPoint);
    }
    var date = new Date(closestPoint[2] * 1000);
    info.innerHTML =
        closestFeature.get('PLT') + ' (' + date.toUTCString() + ')';
    var coordinates = [coordinate, [closestPoint[0], closestPoint[1]]];
    if (line === null) {
      line = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
    } else {
      line.setCoordinates(coordinates);
    }
  }
  map.render();
};

map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  var coordinate = map.getEventCoordinate(evt.originalEvent);
  displaySnap(coordinate);
});

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  displaySnap(evt.coordinate);
});

var imageStyle = new ol.style.Circle({
  radius: 5,
  fill: null,
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.9)',
    width: 1
  })
});
var strokeStyle = new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.9)',
  width: 1
});
map.on('postcompose', function(evt) {
  var vectorContext = evt.vectorContext;
  if (point !== null) {
    vectorContext.setImageStyle(imageStyle);
    vectorContext.drawPointGeometry(point);
  }
  if (line !== null) {
    vectorContext.setFillStrokeStyle(null, strokeStyle);
    vectorContext.drawLineStringGeometry(line);
  }
});

var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  map: map,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 5,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.9)'
      }),
      stroke: null
    })
  })
});

document.getElementById('time').addEventListener('input', function() {
  var value = parseInt(this.value, 10) / 100;
  var m = time.start + (time.duration * value);
  vectorSource.forEachFeature(function(feature) {
    var geometry = /** @type {ol.geom.LineString} */ (feature.getGeometry());
    var coordinate = geometry.getCoordinateAtM(m, true);
    var highlight = feature.get('highlight');
    if (highlight === undefined) {
      highlight = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinate));
      feature.set('highlight', highlight);
      featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(highlight);
    } else {
      highlight.getGeometry().setCoordinates(coordinate);
    }
  });
  map.render();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That example really helped to end hours of searching how to transform the coordinates.