# How to create a circle based on the point on the map in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, proximity

I am trying to create a circle based on the point/coordinate a user clicks. I know how to create a point and a found a function to create a circle based on the point (like a buffer/range ring) but it seems to only work with x,y points (0,0). I tried converting my lon and lat coordinates to X and Y using ol.proj.transform but it doesn't rendered a circle at all.

[Link with the function to create circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996409/draw-a-circle-with-defined-diameter-in-openlayers)

This is what I am trying to create

[image]

```
function createCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius, pointsToEnd) {
            let angleToAdd = 360 / pointsToEnd;
            let coords = [];
            let angle = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < pointsToEnd; i++) {
                angle += angleToAdd;
                let coordX = circleCenterX + circleRadius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
                let coordY = circleCenterY + circleRadius * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
                coords.push([coordX, coordY]);
            }
            return coords;
        }

        function addMarker(coordinates) {
            console.log(coordinates);
            var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([708683.3598450683, 1850098.1965979263]));
            marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 5,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'red'
                    })
                })
            }));
            vectorSource.addFeature(marker);
        }

        function addCircle(coords) {
            // var lonlat1 = ol.proj.transform([coords[0], coords[1]], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');
            // console.log('var lonlat1',lonlat1)
            var circleCoords = createCircle(708683.3598450683, 1850098.1965979263, 20, 180);
            console.log(circleCoords);
            var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([circleCoords]);
            polygon.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
            polygon = new ol.Feature(polygon);
            vectorSource.addFeature(polygon);
        }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wc0sjd61)

Comment: Your problem is the `addMarker` function takes coordinates in the EPSG:3857 projection, the `addCircle` function takes them in the EPSG:4326 projection.  If you want to pass in the same coordinates, you  have to make them consistent.  The circle doesn't appear for  `[708683.3598450683, 1850098.1965979263]` because that is **way** off the map (maximum value for latitude is 90).  [updated fiddle with the same center](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rfbqsum1/1/)  Which projection do you want your coordinates in?

Comment: It can be easily done without using the createCircle function as OpenLayers has a built-in ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle method https://jsfiddle.net/tm1h5a26/

Comment: Be aware that a radius of 20 degrees is not a true circle on the ground as longitudes get closer towards the poles.  You should use `ol.geom.Polygon.circular` to correctly show large radius circles on the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `addMarker` function takes coordinates in the EPSG:3857 projection, the `addCircle` function takes them in the EPSG:4326 projection.

If you want to pass in the same coordinates, you have to make them consistent.

The circle doesn't appear for `[708683.3598450683, 1850098.1965979263]` because that is way off the map (the maximum value for latitude is 90 degrees).

```
addCircle(ol.proj.toLonLat([708683.3598450683, 1850098.1965979263]));
addMarker([708683.3598450683, 1850098.1965979263]);
```

[updated fiddle with the same center (but in different projections)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rfbqsum1/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
    zoom: 3
  })
});
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    features: []
  }),
});
map.addLayer(layer);
var vectorSource = layer.getSource();

function createCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius, pointsToEnd) {
  let angleToAdd = 360 / pointsToEnd;
  let coords = [];
  let angle = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < pointsToEnd; i++) {
    angle += angleToAdd;
    let coordX = circleCenterX + circleRadius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    let coordY = circleCenterY + circleRadius * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    coords.push([coordX, coordY]);
  }
  return coords;
}

function addMarker(coordinates) {
  console.log(coordinates);
  var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
  marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 5,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'red'
      })
    })
  }));
  vectorSource.addFeature(marker);
}

function addCircle(coords) {
  // var lonlat1 = ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');
  // console.log('var lonlat1',lonlat1)
  var circleCoords = createCircle(coords[0], coords[1], 20, 180);
  console.log(circleCoords);
  var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([circleCoords]);
  polygon.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  polygon = new ol.Feature(polygon);
  vectorSource.addFeature(polygon);
}

addCircle(ol.proj.toLonLat([708683.3598450683, 1850098.1965979263]));
addMarker([708683.3598450683, 1850098.1965979263]);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" />
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```